# JavaScript for-loop little prob

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a little problem here with the for-loop:

```
var wide = "700px";
        var flat = "5px";

        var pages = new Array("home","links","aktuell","kontakt");

        for(var i=0;i<pages.length;i++) {
            $("."+pages[i]).bind("click", function() {
                for(var j=0;j<pages.length;j++) {
                    var width;
                    if(pages[j] != pages[i])
                        width = flat;
                    else
                        width = wide;
                    $("#"+pages[j]).animate({width: width}, "slow");
                }       

            });
            $("#"+pages[i]).bind("click", function() {
                for(var k=0;k<pages.length;k++) {
                    var width;
                    if(pages[k] != pages[i])
                        width = flat;
                    else
                        width = wide;
                    $("#"+pages[k]).animate({width: width}, "slow");
                }

            });
        }
```

actually it should produce the following output, but why doesn't it?

```
    $(".home").bind("click", function() {
      $("#home").animate({width: wide}, "slow");
      $("#links").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#aktuell").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#kontakt").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
    });  
    $("#home").bind("click", function() {
      $("#home").animate({width: wide}, "slow");
      $("#links").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#aktuell").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#kontakt").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
    });
    $(".links").bind("click", function() {
      $("#links").animate({width: wide}, "slow");
      $("#home").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#aktuell").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#kontakt").animate({width: flat}, "slow");

    });
     $("#links").bind("click", function() {
      $("#links").animate({width: wide}, "slow");
      $("#home").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#aktuell").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#kontakt").animate({width: flat}, "slow");

    });     
    $(".aktuell").bind("click", function() {
      $("#links").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#home").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#aktuell").animate({width: wide}, "slow");
      $("#kontakt").animate({width: flat}, "slow");

    });
    $("#aktuell").bind("click", function() {
      $("#links").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#home").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#aktuell").animate({width: wide}, "slow");
      $("#kontakt").animate({width: flat}, "slow");

    });     
    $(".kontakt").bind("click", function() {
      $("#links").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#home").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#aktuell").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#kontakt").animate({width: wide}, "slow");
    });
    $("#kontakt").bind("click", function() {
      $("#links").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#home").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#aktuell").animate({width: flat}, "slow");
      $("#kontakt").animate({width: wide}, "slow");
    });
```

Can someone find the error? I've tried to give it all as output and it worked fine but when I try to use it on the website it's just not working.

Comment: nested for loops? oh boy.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Hmm...what's so bad about nested for loops?

Comment: @basilikum - if they are absolutely and unequivocally necessary, nothing. if they aren't, everything.

Comment: by the time your click handler executes, i is (and forever will be) 4, so when you do `pages[j] != pages[i]` the result is always truth.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea and what's wrong with the nested for loop in this case? How would you avoid it?

Comment: @basilikum - i would have coded it an entirely different way, just giving a class to the "active" page (like `$(pages[i]).addClass('ActivePage')` or something), and setting it to `wide` and everything else to `flat`. that's just off the top of my head though, point is there is likely a way to avoid all that processing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var wide = "700px";
var flat = "5px";
var pages = ["home","links","aktuell","kontakt"];
var selectors = [];

for(var i in pages) {
    selectors.push('.' + pages[i]);
    selectors.push('#' + pages[i]);
}

$(selectors.join()).bind("click", function() {
    for(var j=0;j<pages.length;j++) {
        var width;
        if(pages[j] != pages[i])
            width = flat;
        else
            width = wide;
        $("#"+pages[j]).animate({width: width}, "slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: there's a bit more detail in the question, #links is not always wide.

Comment: now is OK? I dont know where exactly you have problem, so I just little improved your code

Comment: This still won't work. i will always be 3.

Comment: what 3? binds or animations ? or what?

Answer (score 1):

When you write this :

```
$("#"+pages[j]).animate({width: width}, "slow");
```

you're not outputting anything, you're executing it. If you need dynamically generated javascript, I would suggest using server-side code to dynamically generate it.

But another, and probably the best option, would be to make your javascript more global cause it is very redundant...

Comment: Thanks in contrast to all the other annoying answers yours helped me. Don't know why I doesn't thought about server-side code. Now it's working!

Comment: You're welcome ! Maybe you could also accept my answer then ? but thanks already for the upvote :-) That said, I would strongly suggest to review you JS though, especially if the site's subject to future changes/evolution. This code is going to be hard to maintain in that case.